# JMeter - Show selected steps from in the grafana

Tags: jmeter, grafana, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have situation with JMeter and grafana,I have a script with sixteen steps but I want to show only 8 of them in Grafana.

So far I used Backend Listener, added it to the Thread Group and voila - everything is working and results can be read from Grafana but now I want to show only 8.

I can't break it on two different scripts...It must be one script in one Thread Group

Comment: Can you add backend listeners under relevant samplers?

Answer (score 0):

Put the specific 8 requests and Backend Listener **under same controller**, even [Simple Logic Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) to report only them to Grafana

> Simple Logic Controller lets you organize your Samplers and other Logic Controllers. Unlike other Logic Controllers, this controller provides no functionality beyond that of a storage device.

Comment: What if I have sixteen steps and the steps to show are not one after the other? This is how it looks like:
1. step to appearance
1A. Step to non-appearance
2. Step to appearance
2A. Step to non-appearance
3. and so on....

Answer (score 0):

Please check elastic search backed listener.

> **Filters**
>
> Only send the samples you want by using Filters! Simply type them as
>   follows in the appropriate field : filter1;filter2;filter3 or
>   sampleLabel_must_contain_this.

Reference;-https://github.com/delirius325/jmeter-elasticsearch-backend-listener

In backend listener, there is also a field name samplersRegex or sample list (based on different implementation). Check that if that can help you to put filter.

I have not tried this but with the above information it seems there is a possibility of this.

Kindly check if this helps.

Comment: I will try. Thanks.